# assign operator to variable in python?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, operators

Usual method of applying mathematics to variables is

```
a * b
```

Is it able to calculate and manipulate two operands like this?

```
a = input('enter a value')
b = input('enter a value') 
op = raw_input('enter a operand')
```

Then how do i connect op and two variables `a` and `b`?
I know I can compare op to `+`, `-`, `%`, `$` and then assign and compute....

But can i do something like `a op b`, how to tell compiler that op is an operator?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use the operator module and a dictionary:

```
import operator
ops = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.div
}   
op_char = input('enter a operand')
op_func = ops[op_char]
result = op_func(a, b)
```

Comment: For python 3.x the `operator.truediv` or `operator.floordiv` should be used instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: additionally, using op_func in this way doesn't work. As the edit queue on this answer is full I've fixed these errors in an answer below (assuming this answer remains ACCEPTED w/ 76 upvotes...)

Comment: @RobertHoughton: what do you claim "doesn't work" with this answer? (I don't know what you mean by "the edit queue" either, but that's maybe just something I don't see.)

Answer (score 11):

The operator module http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html exposes functions corresponding to practically all Python operators. You can map operator symbols to those functions to retrieve the proper function, then assign it to your op variable and compute op(a, b).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a really old thread, but I believe at the time people didn't know about the `eval` function (Maybe it came with Python 3). So here's an updated answer to the question

```py
a = input('enter a value')
b = input('enter a value') 
op = input('enter an operand')
expression = a + op + b # simple string concatenation
result = eval(expression)
```

If the input is not expected to be valid all the time `ast.literal_eval` can be used instead. It raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.
Eg. if `a`, `b` and `op` are respectively 5, 10, + then
`result` is 15

Comment: It should be expression = a + c + b . btw, using eval for user input is a bad idea. ast.literal_eval is better.

Comment: @SilentGuy you're very much right! I've updated my answer

Comment: `eval` wasn't new to Python 3. The reason people aren't suggesting it is because it is not safe to use on user input. It can execute any Python expression (with any side effects) that someone types in. Also, `literal_eval` only evaluates literals. It cannot evaluate an arithmetic expression like `'5+10'`.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` cannot do arithmetic in general, or deal with other operators. It can only handle `+` and `-` [because of a quirk in the Python grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584417/why-does-ast-literal-eval5-7-fail).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to compare the user's inputted string to your list of operands by hand. There is no analogue of int() here, since operators are keywords in the language and not values.

Once you've compared that input string to your list of operands and determined the operator that it corresponds to, you can use the Python standard library's [operator module](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) to calculate the result of applying the operator to your two operands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator module to create a dictionary. From the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) of that module:

> "The operator module exports a set of efficient functions
> corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python. For example,
> operator.add(x, y) is equivalent to the expression x+y."

```
import operator
ops = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv
}   
op_char = input('enter a operand')
a = 1
b = 2
result = ops[op_char](a,b)
print(result)
```