# Python Comparison Evaluator Substitution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to substitute a comparison marker based on the context of a string. I'm doing it in part with a PyQt5 experiment on Python 3.5.

For example:

```
line = "<"

if 1 line 2:
    print("False")
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I considered using a test case as such:

```
if line == "<":
    if 1 < 2:
        print("False")
```

etc, etc, but this gets long, especially with iterative "if" statements.
Ex.:

```
if pt1 < pt1_target:
    if pt2 > pt2_target:
        etc.
```

Or if this is not possible, does anyone have any solution to avoid a massive, catch-all "if" statement block for each branch? I plan on putting a little instruction in so `line` ends up substituting for the correct python equivalent, such as `"="` instead of the correct `"=="`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check also [How to pass an operator to a python function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591778/how-to-pass-an-operator-to-a-python-function), [assign operator to variable in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983139/assign-operator-to-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the functions from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module:

```
from operator import eq, ne, lt, le, gt, ge

operator_functions = {
    '=': eq,
    '!=': ne,
    '<': lt,
    '<=': le,
    '>': gt,
    '>=': ge,
}

operator = # whatever

if operator_functions[operator](a, b):
    do_whatever()
```

Comment: Is that `'=': eq` on purpuse, to say that those do not have to conform to standard Python operator syntax?

Comment: @tobias_k: That was deliberate, since it sounded from the question like the input would be using `=` instead of `==`. I probably should have put in a comment or something about that.

Comment: @user2357112 I like that I don't have to add instructions for what the operator needs to look like, the natural "=" works. Thanks!

Comment: if you're worried about variations in input you can put both `'=': eq, '==': eq, ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to map the operator string to the corresponding function in the `operator` module:

```
import operator

ops = {'>': operator.gt,
       '<': operator.lt,
       '==': operator.eq,
       # etc...
      }

op_string = '<'
if ops[op_string](1, 2):
    print('True')
# or this...
print(ops[op_string](1, 2))
```

Note that this example prints `True`. Your example seemed to negate the logic such that `1 < 2` would evaluate to `False` -  if that's what you want then you can switch around the logic:

```
if ops[op_string](1, 2):
    print 'False'
# or this...
print(not ops[op_string](1, 2))
```

Or you could change the operator mapping:

```
ops = {'<': operator.ge, ...}
print(ops[op_string](1, 2))
# False
```