# Why does ast.literal_eval('5 * 7') fail?

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

Why does the literal evaluation of `5 * 7` fail, while `5 + 7` doesn't?

```
import ast

print(ast.literal_eval('5 + 7'))
# -> 12

print(ast.literal_eval('5 * 7'))
# -> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at ...>
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#ast.literal_eval) doesn't explain this.

I found that problem after answering this question on SO: [Getting the result of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578561/1513933).

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is less powerful and therefore less dangerous than plain `eval`. I guess that makes it the lesser of two evals... :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval()` accepts `+` in the evaluated data because `5+2j` (complex number<sup>*</sup>) are valid literals. The same applies to `-`. To keep the code simple, no attempt is made to exclude `+` or `-` as a binary operators.

No other operators are allowed; the function is *supposed* to only accept literals, not expressions.

In other words, that `5 + 7` works is a bug, but one that is hard to fix without breaking support for constructing complex numbers. The [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ast.py#l38) limits the use to operands that are numbers, unary `+` and `-`, or other binary operators (so you can't use these to concatenate lists or produce a set difference).

Also see several related Python bugtracker entries: [#25335 *ast.literal_eval fails to parse numbers with leading "+"*](http://bugs.python.org/issue25335), [#22525 *ast.literal_eval() doesn't do what the documentation says*](http://bugs.python.org/issue22525) and [#4907 *ast.literal_eval does not properly handled complex numbers*](http://bugs.python.org/issue4907)

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically speaking, `2j` is a valid literal; Python parses `5+2j` as `int(5) binop(+) complex(0, 2)`, and only later produces a `complex(5, 2)` object from the result, when actually executing the addition.

Comment: Thank you Martjn, I suspected something like this. Does it means that the AST is the result of the evaluation? I hope it is not.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: the function builds an AST from the string, then uses the AST to build the result. So the string is *parsed only*, not directly executed. See the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ast.py#l38).

Answer (score 7):

The question is not "why is `*` not accepted" but rather "why is `+` accepted at all".

`ast.literal_eval` can parse literals, but not expressions. However, in Python, complex numbers are not expressed as a single literal value; instead they consist of the real part and imaginary part added together; the imaginary part is signalled with `j`. `literal_eval` thus needs to support binary `+` and `-` to support complex number constants such as `1 + 2j` or `-3.4e-5 - 1.72e9j`.

In many versions, including Python 3.5, `literal_eval` is much more lax than it *needs* to be - it accepts any chain of additions and subtractions for as long as both the left and right-hand sides evaluate to *any* number, thus `(1 + 3) + 2 + (4 - 5)` is still parsed, even if it is not complex constant consisting of real + 
imaginary part.

---

`+` and `-` are not accepted unconditionally: if you try to add 2 lists together, it will fail, even though it can parse list literals, and addition is defined for lists:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1] + [2]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x7fdddbe785f8>
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1, 2]')
[1, 2]
>>> [1] + [2]
[1, 2]
```