# Python: Mathematical Operations using Operators from a list

Tags: python, list, math, operators

Say I have a list with mathematical operators in it, like this

```
operators = ['+','-','*','/']
```

And I am taking a random operator from here, like this

```
op = random.choice(operators)
```

If I take two numbers, say 4 and 2, how can I get Python to do the mathematical operation (under the name 'op') with the numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You better do **not specify the operators as text**. Simply use *lambda expressions*, or the `operator` module:

```
import operator
import random

operators = [operator.add,operator.sub,operator.mul,operator.floordiv]
op = random.choice(operators)
```

You can then call the `op` by calling it with two arguments, like:

```
result = op(2,3)
```

For example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> operators = [operator.add,operator.sub,operator.mul,operator.floordiv]
>>> op = random.choice(operators)
>>> op
<built-in function sub>
>>> op(4,2)
2
```

So as you can see, the `random` picked the `sub` operator, so it subtracted `2` from `4`.

In case you want to define an function that is not supported by `operator`, etc. you can use a lambda-expression, like:

```
operators = [operator.add,lambda x,y:x+2*y]
```

So here you specified a function that takes the parameters `x` and `y` and calculates `x+2*y` (of course you can define an arbitrary expression yourself).

Comment: Thank you! I have tried using operator.div but I keep getting an error?

Comment: @DW_0505: yeah there is no `operator.div`. It is either `operator.floordiv` or `operator.truediv` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv) for a list of operators).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eval` if you are absolutely certain that what you are passing to it is safe like so:

```
num1 = 4
num2 = 2
operators = ['+','-','*','/']
op = random.choice(operators)
res = eval(str(num1) + op + str(num2))
```

Just keep in mind that `eval` executes code without running any checks on it so take care. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748202/valueerror-malformed-string-when-using-ast-literal-eval) for more details on the topic when using `ast` to do a safe evaluation.

Comment: `eval(..)` is considered dangerous. You better avoid it, unless you have absolutely no choice.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Agreed. I'm just providing an answer with the given parameters :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You can use the much safer `literal_eval` from the  `ast` module instead

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: perhaps it is better to provide a note about the possible risks it implies.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `literal_eval` won't work with all operators, try `ast.literal_eval('2*3')`; I'm actually surprised it works with `+` and `-`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Scratch that, it was getting the `+` all the time. That is really weird though.. I am surprised the other way around..

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Sorry about that. I rolled it back.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You can also add this link to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748202/valueerror-malformed-string-when-using-ast-literal-eval

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I'm actually unclear on the rules for this, why does `ast.literal_eval` work for `+`,`-` but not other operators like `*`, `/` or `**`? I always thought it wouldn't work for any operators. The docs don't help me https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: @Chris_Rands It seems that in some cases, additions and subtractions also fail. See the link above,

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584417/why-does-ast-literal-eval5-7