# Operations in `ast.literal_eval()`

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I was searching for a safe way to eval simple arithmetic expressions. I'm aware of the difficulties of making `eval()` "more safe", but then I learned about [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html)

I tried it, with the following example:

```py
>>> ast.literal_eval("1+1")
2
```

Nice! Now try 1 times 1...

```py
>>> ast.literal_eval("1*1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jldiaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/home/jldiaz/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x7fac8830aa58>
```

What does this mean? Malformed string? However it can be parsed without errors:

```py
>>> result = ast.parse("1*1")
>>> ast.dump(result)
'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=1), op=Mult(), right=Num(n=1)))])'
```

The AST looks ok, and the operation to perform is `Mult()`. However it fails. Apparently it is the operation which is failing, because the AST for the first succesful experiment was identical, only with `op=Add()`.

I tried other operations. Division (`/`), integer division (`//`) and modulo (`%`) all fail. Only addition (`+`) and substraction (`-`) seem to work.

Am I missing something? Surprisingly I was unable to find any information about this problem or the operations supported by `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: You'll need to build a proper parser for a calculater, `liter_eval` works for addition and subtraction but only because of complex numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584417/why-does-ast-literal-eval5-7/

Comment: A second relevant dupe target: jfs has a very nice solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string