# Programmatically define Python operators such as & or |

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

is it possible to define programmatically some Python operators like `&` or `|`?

Something like the below would be ideal

```
logical_op = '|'
var1 = var2 = True
eval(f'var1 {logical_op} var2')
```

eval execution should return `True`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? What doesn't work right now?

Comment: operator overloading I think @iz_

Comment: it works just fine, using standard operator class. I love Python :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983144/11230028 This would help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [assign operator to variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983139/assign-operator-to-variable-in-python)

Comment: Not exactly, I'll edit my question. Also I'd like to accumulate more values than the one accepted by default by this operator. e.g: VAR1 AND VAR2 AND VAR3, by default `and_` only takes two parameters (you can add more but they'll be ignored)