# How to dynamically store and execute equations and functions

Tags: python, django

During my current project, I have been receiving data from a set of long-range sensors, which are sending data as a series of bytes. Generally, due to having multiple types of sensors, the bytes structures and data contained are different, hence the need to make the functionality more dynamic as to avoid having to hard-code every single setup in the future (which is not practical).

The server will be using Django, which I believe is irrelevant to the issue at hand but I have mentioned just in case it might have something that can be used.

The bytes data I am receiving looks like this:

`b'B\x10Vu\x87%\x00x\r\x0f\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00ad;l'`

And my current process looks like this:

- Take the first bytes to get the deviceID (`deviceID = val[0:6].hex()`)
- Look up the format to be used in the `struct.unpack()` (here: `>BBHBBhBHhHL` after removing the first bytes for the id.

Now, the issue is the next step. Many of the datas I have have different forms of per-processing that needs to be done. F.e. some values need to be ran with a join statement (e.g. `".".join(str(values[2])` ) while others need some simple mathematical changes (`-113 + 2 * values[4]`) and finally, others needs a simple logic check (`values[7]==0x80`) to return a boolean value.

My question is, what's the best way to code those methods? I would really like to avoid hardcoding them, but it almost seems like the best idea. another idea I saw was to store the functionalities as a string and execute them such as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python), but I've been reading that its a very bad idea, and that it also slows down execution. The last idea I had was to hardcode some general functions only and use something similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983139/assign-operator-to-variable-in-python), but this doesn't solve the issue of having to hard-code every new sensor-type, which is not realistic in a live-installation. Are there any better methods to achieve the same thing?

I have also looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string), with the idea that some functionality can be somehow optimized as an equation, but I didn't see that a possibility for *every* occurrence, especially when any string manipulation is needed at all.

Additionally, is there a possibility of using some maths to apply some basic string manipulation? I can hard-code one string manipulation maybe, but to be honest this whole thing has been bugging me...

Finally, I am considering if I go with the function storing as string then executing, is there a way to set some "security" to avoid any malicious exploitation? Since such a method is... awful insecure to say the least.

However, after almost a week total of searching I am so far unable to find a better solution than storing functions as a string and running `eval` on them, despite not liking that option. If anyone finds a better option before then, I would be extremely grateful to any tips or ideas.

**Appendum:** Minimum code that can be used to show-case and test different methods:

```
import struct

def decode(input):
    val = bytearray(input)
    deviceID = val[0:6].hex()
    del(val[0:6])
    print(deviceID)
    values = list(struct.unpack('>BBHBBhBHhHL', val))
    print(values)
    # Now what?

decode(b'B\x10Vu\x87%\x00x\r\x0f\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00ad;l')
```

Comment: I do not see any way to avoid coding functions at least for each case you will have, but what you could do is to make as easy as possible the switch. Before Python 3.10 there were no switch-case statement, but there were some workaround, and maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement) would help you a bit.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks, I will check it out. Unfortunately as far as I know, my web-hosting has a maximum of python 3.9 installed. But I can possibly send them a request to upgrade to python 3.10 if I can find the feature an advantage enough to go for it.