# Can I store a logical condition inside a variable

Tags: python

For example, I have this code:

```
a = 33
b = 200
if b > a:
  # do some thing
```

I want to switch the `>` sign without using the else/if-else condition to `==` or `<`, is there a way I can store logic condition in a variable x and do something like:

```
if b x a:
  # do something
```

Comment: No, `x = >` isn't valid syntactically, but you could use a _function_ - `if compare(b, a):`. Then just use https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html.

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn string into operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator)

Comment: my code is just an example code, its a complex logic and some time i have to just change the sign manually.

Comment: This seems to me as an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem why do you want to do it in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `operator.lt(a, b)` or `operator.gt(a, b)` or `operator.eq(a,b)`.

```
import operator
a = 33
b = 200
x = operator.lt
if x(a,b):
  print("hello world")
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided they are just numbers (integers or floats), you could multiply both arguments by positive or negative 1, which switches the `<` sign

```
a = 5
b = 6
direction = -1

if direction * a < direction * b:
    # do something
    pass
```

Note this is a mathematical solution rather than a programming one

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the eval built-in function
[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```
>>> a = "5"
>>> b = "*"
>>> c="1"
>>> eval(a+b+c)
5
>>> d = ">"
>>> eval(a+d+c)
True
```

Similar thread:[assign operator to variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983139/assign-operator-to-variable-in-python)

Comment: NEVER advocate `eval` without mentioning the high risk of using it. A must read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 0):

For this use-case you could get some inspiration from the "spaceship operator" ([three-way comparison on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison)) available in Perl or PHP.

```
def cmp3w(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return 0
    return -1 if a < b else 1
```

Then the meaning of `cmp3w(a,b) == x` condition depends on the variable `x` (+1 for gt, 0 for eq, -1 for lt).